# How to detect button tap in a UITableViewCell which is in a UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm trying to detect button tap in a `UITableViewCell` which is in a `UICollectionViewCell`.

`UICollectionView`'s delegate and dataSource is my `ViewController`. There is one `UITableView` in every `UICollectionViewCell`. And the `UITableViewCell`'s delegate and dataSource is the `UICollectionViewCell`.

I need to detect button taps in the `ViewController`.

**ViewController**

```
@IBOutlet collectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
}
```

**UICollectionView**

```
@IBOutlet tableView: UITableView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}
```

**UITableViewCell**

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: CustomButton) {
    // Detect Button Tap in ViewController
}
```

Comment: add some additional code

Comment: call delegate and datasource method of tableView in your collection view cell class

Comment: Well if its the only button in the cell, you could rely on table view delegate didSelect OR else you can create a delegate pattern OR use a closure to notify controller on tap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your own delegate for that.

```
protocol ButtonDelegate: class {
    func buttonTapped(_ button: UIButton)
}
```

Then, implement it in your `ViewController` and do whatever you want to happen when the button gets tapped.

In your `UICollectionView` and your `UITableViewCell`, add a property:

`weak var buttonDelegate: ButtonDelegate?`

And then, modify your `UITableViewCell`:

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: CustomButton) {
    buttonDelegate?.buttonTapped(sender)
}
```

In the `ViewController` you have to set the delegate on the `UICollectionView`:

```
collectionView.buttonDelegate = self
```

At last, in your `cellForRowAt` method in your `UICollectionView`, set the `buttonDelegate` property of the `UITableViewCell` to the `buttonDelegate` of the `UICollectionView`, which is your `ViewController`:

```
cell.buttonDelegate = buttonDelegate
```

Comment: I would pass the cell to the delegate method, rather than button.  That way the delegate can easily determine the appropriate data model item that corresponds to the button.

Comment: how can this work if you don't set delegate of collection view cells?

Comment: Hey @fabianbraach, thanks for you answer! I was hoping to find a direct way to detect the tap in the cell from the viewcontroller but i guess this is how it works. It's like moving the delegate(?) to the upper classes, right? And should i always do this in this kind of situations?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to use delegate pattern.

---

So you need one protocol for table view cell and one for collection view cell

```
protocol TableCellDelegate: class {
     func buttonPressed(_ sender: CustomButton)
}

protocol CollectionCellDelegate: class {
     func buttonInTableCellPressed(_ sender: CustomButton)
}
```

now create `delegate` variables for cell subclasses

```
class TableCell: ... {
    weak var delegate: TableCellDelegate?
}

class CollectionCell: ... {
    weak var delegate: CollectionCellDelegate?
}
```

continue with implementing `TableCellDelegate` to `CollectionView` and call method on cell's delegate inside table cell delegate's method

```
extension CollectionCell: TableCellDelegate {
    func buttonPressed(_ sender: CustomButton) {
        delegate?.buttonInTableCellPressed(sender)
    }
}
```

next implement `CollectionCellDelegate` to your view controller

```
extension ViewController: CollectionCellDelegate {
    func buttonInTableCellPressed(_ sender: CustomButton) {
        ... // this is called when button in table view cell is pressed
    }
}
```

Now, don't forget to set delegate of collection cell inside `cellForItemAt` in `ViewController` and delegate of table cell inside `cellForRowAt` in `CollectionCell`

```
class ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        ...
        cell.delegate = self
        ...
    }
}

class CollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        ...
        cell.delegate = self
        ...
    }
}
```

Now, finally, call method on delegate inside table cell when button is pressed

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: CustomButton) {
    delegate?.buttonPressed(sender)
}
```

Comment: I would pass the cell to the delegate method, rather than button.  That way the delegate can easily determine the appropriate data model item that corresponds to the button.

Comment: @Paulw11 from his question isn't very clear for what he needs button. Anyway, if he needs to pass appropriate data model item, he can pass instead of button just that item, right?

Comment: Hey, @RobertDresler , thanks for your answer! Looks like this is a correct answer too but i accepted the other answer because it was the first one and also solved my problem. Have a nice day!

Comment: @Sercan But, his answer isn’t correct, he doesn’t show you that you need to set delegate of the collection view cell so his answer isn’t first correct answer ;)

Comment: @RobertDresler Personally I wouldn't have a view, like a cell, bound to a model object directly.

Comment: @Paulw11 do you mean, model variable inside cell subclass?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I would configure the cell from the view controller, if possible.

Comment: @Paulw11 what about data source for table view inside collection view cell?

Comment: I would use a delegate pattern so that the CollectionViewCell could pass the request for table data back to the model/view controller, but there is no one "right way"

Comment: @Paulw11 so collectionviewcell would request data by calling some method on its delegate and view controller then would send these data by calling some method on its delegate, right? Oh, I’ve never thought about this option! Thank you for it! :)

Comment: @Sercan anyway, I look at it and my answer was posted earlier... if you care about this :D